# Popup menu exits Immersive Mode

Tags: android

I've set up my application to use Immersive Sticky Mode, but I also use some elements that are above the Activity context and that when the user interacts with them, the application exits Immersive Mode and the status bar is displayed again. These elements are a dialog box and a popup menu for a toolbar. I was able to prevent the status bar from appearing when the dialog was called through the following code inside my showDialog method:

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

However, I am not able to do the same with the popup menu. These are the methods of creating and selecting the menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int choosenId = item.getItemId();

    switch (choosenId){
        case R.id.btn1:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn1);

        break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn2);

        break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn3);

        break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            lblTitle.setText(R.string.btn4);

        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And this is the xml of my toolbar:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundDarker"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/button_back_orange" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

OBS: I'm already using these codes on my Activities:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (hasFocus) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }else{
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
}
```